# Django - wont let me add a new field to my model because 1054, "Unknown column 'field list'")

Tags: django

I am trying to simply add a boolean field to a model in my database following the simple rules:

```
- add field to model
- python manage.py makemigrations app
- python manage.py migrate app
```

Works all but 99% of the time. So during the second step (makemigrations), with my newly added field in my model raring to go, i get an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'model.field' in 'field list'")
```

Excellent. its not letting me make migrations by adding a new field..... because it cant find the field that I am trying to newly add... makes perfect sense!

Anyway, I have gone as far as deleting all my migrations, removing my new field, making migrations again, migrating... all fine - so now i have only 1 migration file (0001)...

Follow the same steps as above... ERROR

Am i missing something ridiculous here? I mean, adding a field to a model is very simple, and I have done it probably 1000 times. Why does Django tease me so

EDIT: Answer:

OK I have done it.

After deleting the migrations file, truncating the migrations table and migrating with 0001_initial.py, I made an empty migrations file (python manage.py makemigrations --empty app) and added the field in manually.... then I migrated and it worked! Baffled at this to be honest, but at least the change has been made:

- Delete all migration files
- Truncate the django_migrations table
- comment the new boolean field
- run python manage.py makemigrations
- run python manage.py migrate --fake
- run python manage.py makemigrations --empty app
- add field in manually to the empty migrations file in the operations:

  ```
  migrations.AddField('modelName', 'fieldName', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
  ```
- run python manage.py migrate
- uncomment the new boolean field so it represents what you made in the migrations operations

Comment: Well by removing all the old migration files, now the new migration file will build a database *from scratch*. But the database is not made from scratch, it has already a lot of tables (and columns). So it will complain about duplicate tables/colums/etc.

Comment: But this error happened before I did that. And when I did that, the migration worked fine. Its when im trying to add a new field, that it complains. Nothing to do with any duplicates...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Disclaimer**- *Follow this only on local system, for production do understand the steps and then execute.*

Kindly follow these steps:

- Delete all migration files
- Truncate the django_migrations table
- comment the new boolean field
- run `python manage.py makemigrations`
- run `python manage.py migrate --fake`
- Uncomment the boolean field
- run `python manage.py makemigrations`
- run `python manage.py migrate`

Generally these steps solve any kind of migration problem

An another reason can be if you are using **django_rest_framework** then the serialiser too needs to be updated as per your model change.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have done everything, but when i uncomment the boolean field, and run makemigrations it still happens!!! Argh!!!

Comment: I really dont understand this. I have done so many migrations, why does this happen now?

Comment: OK I have done it: After deleting the migrations file, truncating the migrations table and migrating with 0001_initial.py, I made an empty migrations file (python manage.py makemigrations --empty app) and added it in manually.... then I migrated and it worked! Baffled at this to be honest, but at least the change has been made. Thanks for your help

Comment: glad I could help. I have also face such issues in the past. This made me comeup with such strategy. It has rescued me always. You should accept my answer so that others don't have to bang their head on this topic anymore.

Comment: Your solution does not fix the problem. The only way I solve this: manually create columns in the database and then make migrations.

Comment: @AlexeiMarinichenko: Most of the time it has helped me and others fix such problem. There might be corner cases where it might fails. I would love to know more about the issue where the steps I mentioned couldn't solve

Comment: send you my love :-P

Comment: @Nairum solution :  For me, the simplest solution that worked without having to delete and rebuilt everything. after `makemigrations`, don't forget to `migrate --fake` to avoid duplicate field error

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that has persisted with me and lead me down a lot of rabbit holes dropping tables etc. A simple solution I have found is answering "N" when django asks you if you are renaming a field of that model (when running makemigrations). What that then essentially performs is a deletion of your previous field and creates the new field. Be careful as you may lose data on existing field so this works with fields which are either new or relatively easy to 'refill' their data required. You may need to run  --fake if you get an error with regards to not being able to 'drop field' when migrating after makemigrations. If you would like to go back to your migration state before the problem you may need to delete the migrations you have done since then and try the above solution.

Update:
I did the above for a Boolean field and my data was kept. Even though I said N, it seems as if it is essentially a renaming.

Answer (score -1):

Another source of the problem:  I have a ModelForm based on the model.  The ModelForm definition defines two extra fields.  I had to comment out those two fields from the Form definition before doing the migration steps.  Once the migration was done, I un-commented the two fields.

Comment: This is not the answer that's why please migrate this answer to comment section to inform others. Create an answer when there is an answer which helps OP and others.Thanks

Comment: Not clear what you mean, Ahmed.  The question identifies a problem which may have several root causes.  I have addressed one possible cause of the problem.

Comment: You addressed not answered! and this is answers section.